# Using a fixed .aux file

Tags: loops, auxiliary-files, scripts

I teach a large class of about 600+ students and like to preformat my exams with names, tutorials, etc. I create an exam template in LaTeX, then have a script fill in the necessary information, compile, and append the results into a pdf to send to the printer.

The system works great as long as the tests are compiled consecutively -- one after another. To speed things up though, I'd like to run the for-loop in parallel. The problem is, any autogenerated, compile-twice information doesn't appear correctly. I figure this is because several processes are writing to the same .aux file simultaneously, which screws the system up. But, the .aux file information isn't actually changing on each run, so I'd like a way of "permanently" fixing the .aux file.

I could have the for-loop write to a unique aux file for each compile, but this would mean running two compiles for each exam. In series, each exam only needs one compile because the .aux file doesn't need to update. Is there a way to tell my LaTeX distribution to use the .aux file as-is?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but are you looking for `\nofiles` (must be written in the `preamble`)?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I *think* I want the .aux file to be read from but not written to, but that's only my guess for why I cannot compile my documents in parallel. Your idea seems like a good one, but very very weird behaviour manifests. All but one process throws a LaTeX error, and that process then absorbs and hybridizes the output of the other processes at termination, (which should be impossible). I'm having trouble capturing the error because the log information is overwritten, so I'm going to have to play with the code a bit.

Comment: reading but not writing aux (and toc etc) is exactly what `\nofiles` sets up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay perfect. Let me take a look at this then, since I'm getting weird errors popping up, so maybe that's an issue with the external script rather than LaTeX.

Comment: off-topic: Before of reinventing the wheel with the exams, one should know that for Mac OS X and Linux exist [AMC](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/).

Comment: @Fran That's an interesting link, thanks. Though, it doesn't look related to what I'm doing. I just want each paper to have the student's name, tutorial, student number, etc on each paper already, rather than have the student enter that info. As for online evaluations/tests/marking, I actually developed my own software for this.

Comment: @TylerHolden I figured that it was not related, thus the "off-topic" warning. ;)